# What is this diode bridge used for in this circuit?

Tags: circuit-analysis, diodes, dali

I'm currently trying to figure out how this circuit work :[image]

I found this in a microchip documentation dealing with DALI ([Digital Addressable Lighting Interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Addressable_Lighting_Interface)) protocol. The DALI protocol is mostly used to communicate with lighting equipment. 
I can already understand what is going on for the most part but I'm still having trouble with the function of the diode bridge. I know that diode bridge are used to convert AC to DC voltage. But in this circuit, the input is already a DC voltage, so I'm wondering what is this diode bridge doing exactly?

Comment: It would be useful to link the document this was from

Comment: Ensures only positive polarity pulses are received.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While the DALI bus has DC power on it, the wiring topology is not polarity-sensitive.  That is, either wire can go on either pin of any DALI interface connector.  From the Wikipedia page:

"Each device has a bridge rectifier on its input so it is polarity-insensitive."

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Addressable_Lighting_Interface#Technical_overview

Comment: Idiot-proofing a commercial system makes sense. No one actually read instructions much anymore. At least, not detailed ones.

Comment: It uses the BiPhase encoding scheme to modulate data on changes rather than binary level.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect the bridge is there to protect the circuit and keep it functioning if the DALI bus wires are reversed.

Comment: From the Wikipedia article: *Each device has a bridge rectifier on its input so it is polarity-insensitive.*

Comment: No it is not mainly for protection but for Common Mode Rejection with optical isolation.